# How to call global env variable for gulp protractor

Tags: protractor, yargs

This is gulpfile:

```
gulp.task(
    'protractor', function () {
        var configObj = {
            configFile: config.test + 'protractor.conf.js'
        };
        configObj['args'] =[];//to be able to add multiple parameters

        if (argv.suite) {
            configObj['args'].push (
                '--suite',
                argv.suite
            );
        }

        if (argv.env) {

            if(argv.env.includes("q")){//qa
                argv.baseUrl = "http://xx.qa.yy.com:8080";
            }
            else{//prod
                if(argv.env.includes("p")){
                    argv.baseUrl = "https://xx.yy.com";
                }
                else{//local
                    argv.baseUrl = "localhost:8080";
                }
            }

            configObj['args'] .push(
                '--baseUrl',
                argv.baseUrl
            );
        }
        return gulp.src([])
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(protractor(configObj))
            .on(
                'error', function () {
                    gutil.log('E2E Tests failed');
                    process.exit(1);
                }
            );
    }
);
```

so, in protractor test classes, i can get baseurl with that for exaple

```
 this.getBaseUrl = function () {
    return browser.baseUrl;
};
```

,

because i set here

```
            configObj['args'] .push(
                '--baseUrl',
                argv.baseUrl
            );
```

but i cant get env. it is set here

from console command

```
gulp protractor --env l --suite logout
```

i can see in consloeoutput of that

```
argv.env
```

but i cant call from protractor it. I tried `browser.env`
but did not work. how can i do this?

also i use yargs

```
var argv = require('yargs')//setting default enviroment to qa for testing
    .default({ env : 'qa' })
    .argv;
```

Comment: If you want to get some env variable that is inside the node env. You can access it by using process.env.xxx
for example: process.env.NODE_ENV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `env` global variable or command line option in protractor, You have to pass it as a paramater using `params`. You can do something like this-

```
 if (argv.params.env) {

        if(argv.params.env.includes("q")){//qa
            argv.baseUrl = "http://xx.qa.yy.com:8080";
        }
        else{//prod
            if(argv.params.env.includes("p")){
                argv.baseUrl = "https://xx.yy.com";
            }
            else{//local
                argv.baseUrl = "localhost:8080";
            }
        }
```

Now from console command you can invoke it

```
gulp protractor --params.env 'test' --suite logout
```

You can also access it calling `browser.params.env`

You can always set globals in protractor in config file:

```
exports.config = {
//other config options

params: {
    env: 'qa'
}

};
```

And pass values to the global variables through command line as-

```
protractor conf.js --params.env 'dev'
```